# True or false: There exist's $ \delta>0 $ with $ \mu([\delta,1-\delta])>0 $

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let be $ \mu $ a measure on $ (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}) $ and it is $ \mu([0,1])>0 $. Prove or disprove: It exist's $ \delta>0 $ with $ \mu([\delta,1-\delta])>0 $.

I think it is true. This is my idea:

Consider the sequence $ (I_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}} $ with $ I_n:=[\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}] $. Then it is $ I_n\in \mathcal{B} $ and $ I_n \subseteq I_{n+1} $.

So it follows $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \mu(I_n)=\mu([0,1])>0 $. (**)

Assume for all $ \delta>0 $ it is $ \mu([\delta,1-\delta])=0 $ ($\mu([\delta,1-\delta])<0$ cannot be the case because $ \mu $ is a measure). So it also hold for $ \delta_n:=\frac{1}{n} $ with $ n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2} $. It is $$ 0=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty }\mu([\delta_n,1-\delta_n])=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \mu(I_n)\stackrel{(**)}{=}\mu([0,1])>0 $$
which is a contradiction. So there exist's $ \delta>0 $ with $ \mu([\delta,1-\delta])>0 $.

Is that working?

Comment: No - $\mu = \delta_0$ is a counterexample. The problem with your argument is that $\lim [1/n, 1-1/n]$ is $(0,1),$ not $[0,1].$

Comment: Yeah true. I proved the equation $ \bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}}=]0,1[ $ by showing that each of the relation $ "\subseteq" $ and $ "\supseteq" $ are hold. $ "\subseteq" $ follows immediately and for $ "\supseteq" $ I chosed for $ x\in]0,1[ $ the number $ N\in \mathbb{N} $ with $ N\geq \max\{\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{1-x}\} $.

Comment: Sorry I mean $ N>\max\{\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{1-x}\} $.

Answer (score 1):

As shown by @justt, the claim is false.

As for the OP's argument, here's the error:

$\cup_{n} [\frac1n, 1-\frac1n] = (0,1)$, the ***open*** interval, not the closed interval $[0,1]$,  and therefore $\mu (I_n) \nearrow \mu ( (0,1))=\mu([0,1])-\mu(\{0,1\})$.

Answer (score 0):

The Dirac measure at $0$, which verifies $\mu(\{0\})=1$ and $\mu(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}) = 0$, is a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: Given this, try using this Dirac measure in the steps of your proof to find your mistake.

Comment: Oh ok. But on which point my idea is going wrong?